# Is it possible to find $a$, $b$ such that $(a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find $a$, $b$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $- \infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ such that $(a,b] \cap \mathbb{Q} = \emptyset$?

I need this result for a proof I am doing...

Comment: Is it possible? What do you think? What do you know about the rational numbers inside the real numbers?

Comment: Let $\delta = b-a$. Since $a$, $b$ are real numbers, there are sequences of rational numbers $\alpha_k>a$ and $\beta_k<b$ so that $\alpha_k\to a$ and $\beta_k \to b$ (why?). Then, for adequately large $k$, i.e., $k>k_0$, $|\alpha_k-a|<\delta/2$ and $|\beta_k-b|<\delta/2$. Then for $k>k_0, $(\alpha_k+\beta_k)/2$ is in $(a, b]$ and is a rational number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such pair of numbers because for any two real numbers $a<b$, there exists a rational number $q$ such that $a<q<b$. For a proof, take the decimal expansion of $a$ and $b$ (WLOG, I am assuming $a,b\in[0,1]$ and am taking the expansion without infinitely repeating nines):

$$a=0.a_1a_2a_3\dots\\
b=0.b_1b_2b_3\dots$$

Let $k$ be the first index at which $a_k\neq b_k$. Since $a<b$, it is also true that $a_k<b_k$. Also, let's say that after the index $k$, there are an additional $l$ nines in the decimal expansion of $a$ (so $a_{k+1}=a_{k+2}=\cdots = a_{k+l}=9$ **and** $a_{k+l+1} \neq 9$. Then, the number

$$q=a_1a_2\dots a_{k-1} a_k9\dots 9$$

where the number of appended nines is $l+1$, is smaller than $b$ and larger than $a$.

Comment: I know that if $\mathcal{A}$ is the collection of finite unions of sets of the form $(a,b]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$. How can this be true if $\mathcal{A}$ does not include the empty set? Is there some convention to accommodate this?

Comment: @möbius $\emptyset = (0,0]\cap \mathbb Q$

Comment: So the convention is that 0<0? This would solve my problem

Comment: @möbius Oh, no, that's not true. The set $$\{(a,b]\cap \mathbb Q: a<b\}$$ does **not** contain the empty set.

Answer (score 1):

No. The rationals are dense in the reals.